# Microsoft Access Text ODBC Driver on Windows 7

Tags: windows, delphi, odbc

I created a Delphi application which utilizes an ODBC data source to access text files in csv format.  The driver is the "Microsoft Access Text Driver".  But when I deploy my application on a Windows 7 computer it does not work because this driver is not available (there are only two available in odbcad32: sql native client and sql server)

How can I install this driver?  I have tried to install MDAC, but it doesn't do anything.  No errors or anythinig, but it just shows a quick scroll bar and that is it.  And I have heard that MDAC has been replaced by WDAC on Windows 7.

EDIT: I should add this is Windows 7 Home, not Professional.

Comment: Just wondering - why did you accept skamradt as best answer when you choose to implement fupsduck sugestion?

Comment: Actually I never implemented the suggestion. I only hinted I might in the event the driver could not be installed. In the end I ran the routine from a Widows XP box and bypassed the Windows 7. I kind of think skamradt more directly answers the question: the driver is not available. While what you wrote is good, I view it more a "alternative".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to install the Microsoft Jet driver.  I believe that Microsoft broke it out of MDAC awhile back, and it is no longer be installed by default.

**EDIT** After further research it appears that they have removed the text file drivers from the jet engine entirely.  You can still use the Microsoft ODBC DB Provider for ODBC Drivers to access dBase and Excel files, but no longer text files.

Comment: Did some searches on MS and could find nothing resembling the Jet driver download.

Comment: Ok.  So it sounds like a situation where there is no backwards compatibility.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: If anyone hits this page, the download, now, at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d ("Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable") installs the "Microsoft Access Text Driver" for XPSP3 -> W7. And the last "Jet" downloads are at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=239114#2

Answer (score 6):

You have to run the ODBC Administrator from this location:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

then you will see all the x32 drivers

Answer (score 3):

Project JEDI has an open source [TJvCSVDataSet](http://www.google.nl/search?q=tjvcsvdataset)

Comment: Thanks for making this comment.  But I figure rather than install a new component just for this task I would probably just read it as a stringlist and parse it.

Comment: I wrote JvCsvDataSet. You put it on your form or data module. You make it active. You're done.  You'd rather write parser code than run an installer?

Comment: @Warren: I'd seen JvCSVDataSet, but never used it. I just tested it, and it is indeed that simple to use. Well done, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not lighten it up and use a VCL TStringList with TStringList.LoadFromFile() and forget about ODBC, MDAC, WDAC and whatever else weighs down the task at hand?

Comment: In the end that may be what I end up doing.  The nice thing about using the text driver was the csv file had headers.  So I could access fields by their name.  This a data conversion I need to do. It runs fine on my development machine.  But now I need to run it on target computer.  It's already coded; my hope was this was something simply so I am not forced to rewrite and parse.

Comment: If your target DB table matches the CSV file a simple INSERT INTO table VALUES (TStringList.CommaText) will work and if not use TStringList.Insert, Delete, Move first to make it match.

Comment: I suspect the benefit he gets from using ODBC driver is that it is guaranteed to correctly handle whichever particular flavor of CSV (as there are a dozen, all slightly incompatible) he's dealing with.

Comment: FWIW, JvCsvDataSet handles at least six or seven different CSV encoding variants (relating to quotation and escaping quote marks, backslash handling, and even handles both ANSI/ASCII and UTF8).

Answer (score 1):

I found I could access the Microsoft text Driver if my application is compiled targeting x86 cpus.

Comment: It wasn't about accessing the Text Driver, but actually having the Text driver available.

Comment: I've found this too, though with C#/.net - surely having it available and accessing it are similar? Or were you unable to reference the driver/similar in the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need to install [this package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891) to get the text driver (among others).

Comment: Tried this.  And it installed successfully; but did not provide the drivers in ODBC.  I should add this is a "Windows 7 Premium Home" operating system.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a CSV demo](http://sites.google.com/site/warrenpostma/JvCsvDataDemoNoInstall.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) that doesn't require you to install any components or write any parsing code. If you can call my class .Create method, you can use this code without installing anything.

It uses two unit files that implement the JvCsvDataSet component, which is still a class, which can be instantiated the same way you can create a TStringList, you just create a TJvCsvDatSet.